# IIS + ASP.NET + Multiple sessions each minute with random session id

Tags: asp.net, session, iis

My IIS is starting a new session each minute with different session id as you can see below:

```
2015-05-24 02:05:48,284 WARN  [5gs1h5biysgaovwgxclzoa53 - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:05:48, ID=5gs1h5biysgaovwgxclzoa53
2015-05-24 02:06:48,289 WARN  [i2cw11dcyc444agufblzqw3t - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:06:48, ID=i2cw11dcyc444agufblzqw3t
2015-05-24 02:07:48,290 WARN  [x4d2dqekamnmbqtwcb1xugzv - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:07:48, ID=x4d2dqekamnmbqtwcb1xugzv
2015-05-24 02:08:48,275 WARN  [upllvlwizdkrxzdy4tql3skn - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:08:48, ID=upllvlwizdkrxzdy4tql3skn
2015-05-24 02:09:48,293 WARN  [olf30h2lhy1wjynkwuixi3ko - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:09:48, ID=olf30h2lhy1wjynkwuixi3ko
2015-05-24 02:10:48,283 WARN  [qyqauweqaygcb1ihmptntmzw - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:10:48, ID=qyqauweqaygcb1ihmptntmzw
2015-05-24 02:11:48,304 WARN  [nkbijfuwgwmblcsvqhyjrx01 - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:11:48, ID=nkbijfuwgwmblcsvqhyjrx01
2015-05-24 02:12:48,293 WARN  [ahz35qnkdgdsp02ggutbgkja - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:12:48, ID=ahz35qnkdgdsp02ggutbgkja
2015-05-24 02:13:48,300 WARN  [xym3aeiiwo0z5m00t0mmying - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:13:48, ID=xym3aeiiwo0z5m00t0mmying
2015-05-24 02:14:48,285 WARN  [ihkhdun0vdiddndptascmhww - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:14:48, ID=ihkhdun0vdiddndptascmhww
2015-05-24 02:15:48,300 WARN  [43aa5kqyilwp1faehxc13dgm - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:15:48, ID=43aa5kqyilwp1faehxc13dgm
2015-05-24 02:16:48,280 WARN  [egcdnwzieqozkfoj2ocwy0x2 - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:16:48, ID=egcdnwzieqozkfoj2ocwy0x2
2015-05-24 02:17:48,278 WARN  [svbpgdm5birqzejfqiatmd0h - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:17:48, ID=svbpgdm5birqzejfqiatmd0h
2015-05-24 02:18:48,268 WARN  [v3ejvlkmsilwvw0x4ir1p3ys - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:18:48, ID=v3ejvlkmsilwvw0x4ir1p3ys
2015-05-24 02:19:48,293 WARN  [ge1z4csva4haxwlq0wtc0zyw - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:19:48, ID=ge1z4csva4haxwlq0wtc0zyw
2015-05-24 02:20:48,288 WARN  [qkmvkk20xgohntlcjf5bwtn4 - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:20:48, ID=qkmvkk20xgohntlcjf5bwtn4
2015-05-24 02:21:48,259 WARN  [hvncho3ievxogpwp20gtkhhh - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:21:48, ID=hvncho3ievxogpwp20gtkhhh
2015-05-24 02:21:52,195 WARN  [0l3b3nhpcowsf0q5xogiehq1 - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:21:52, ID=0l3b3nhpcowsf0q5xogiehq1
2015-05-24 02:22:48,269 WARN  [ppqf2nvcazbfdjid0210thvh - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:22:48, ID=ppqf2nvcazbfdjid0210thvh
2015-05-24 02:23:48,259 WARN  [q1zk5sh11hajiqjcosirvwdo - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:23:48, ID=q1zk5sh11hajiqjcosirvwdo
2015-05-24 02:24:48,285 WARN  [rkmo5fuekm1xzh2kssgl0bsi - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:24:48, ID=rkmo5fuekm1xzh2kssgl0bsi
2015-05-24 02:25:48,270 WARN  [t1i3k5nf1oj0ck2xs42f5hay - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:25:48, ID=t1i3k5nf1oj0ck2xs42f5hay
2015-05-24 02:26:46,791 WARN  [ewi5nrnrskiepuy3npmfn4tc - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:26:46, ID=ewi5nrnrskiepuy3npmfn4tc
2015-05-24 02:26:48,281 WARN  [wtqawkfrbpr4wrhvciju1ztr - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:26:48, ID=wtqawkfrbpr4wrhvciju1ztr
2015-05-24 02:27:48,277 WARN  [uwistkkip1t4qqbcnxkbrp0y - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:27:48, ID=uwistkkip1t4qqbcnxkbrp0y
2015-05-24 02:28:48,266 WARN  [kwqwgubrc5v5uf0kibm5dew5 - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:28:48, ID=kwqwgubrc5v5uf0kibm5dew5
2015-05-24 02:29:44,361 WARN  [equu33nbxkmuvh4akwcmzl4v - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:29:44, ID=equu33nbxkmuvh4akwcmzl4v
2015-05-24 02:29:48,272 WARN  [mjki2onf1cvoznblfhkgnpko - ] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 02:29:48, ID=mjki2onf1cvoznblfhkgnpko
```

After some time all sessions are ended at same time.
Anyone know why? Who to prevent this? I've created another site duplicated, with same configurations and this does not happens.

Comment: More information. Is this in your local development environment? Production? Do you have a load balancer?

Comment: Is your IIS receiving requests? What kind of requestw?

Comment: IIS 8.5.9600 @ Windows Server 2012 R2. Is production and does not have a load balancer

Comment: If they are all ended at the exact same time, can you see if it's because of the application pool recycling? Have you verified that there isn't a matching  website hit, perhaps a bot or a service that is pinging the site to see if it's available?

Comment: +1 to @MarkFitzpatrick - the default recycle of app pool is 1740 minutes, and could very much be the cause; you can change the recycling to occur at a specific period of the day

Comment: I have an application pool with .Net v4. if I start the web site without anyone connected, this requests starts

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick I have recycle defined to 0 because I can't have recycle active. and the site is not available on the web. is only in a local network

Comment: what is doing this logging? can you get the client ip of the request

Comment: @JJS I've configured log4net at web.config to do this log

Comment: @cesarfaria suggest you get more details at log entry. client ip and callstack

Comment: You can set the default recycle to 0, but IIS will still recycle it if it needs to such as the case of too much memory used (session is a good cause for this) a fault in a dll that is uncaught, etc.. Check the logs in IIS to see if perhaps something on the network is pinging the server on port 80. Something could be scanning to ensure the network is healthy. A session will always be created for a request if session is turned on, and if that request doesn't pass the cookie back it will keep creating new sessions since it sees the request as coming from a new source.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick great suggestion. need to know who/what making the request and why its not sending the session cookie. is there a magic value to prevent asp.net from starting a session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to your comments I've found what is causing these session starts:

> 2015-05-24 04:17:48,130 WARN  [rskvci3lyd05zfml0h2myee1 -  -
>   IP:10.2.1.78 - Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; PRTG Network Monitor
>   (www.paessler.com); Windows)] Session_Start (): 24-05-2015 04:17:48,
>   ID=rskvci3lyd05zfml0h2myee1

Our customer has a network monitor that checks every minute, causing a session start.

I've used this layout to get the result above:

```
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level [%aspnet-request{ASP.NET_SessionId} - %identity - IP:%aspnet-request{REMOTE_ADDR} - %aspnet-request{http_user_agent}] %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
```

Comment: Why not give your customer a page to monitor which does not use session state?

Comment: could you post the log4net format you used to get this log entry for others?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks, I'll follow your sugestion.

Comment: In my case, a bot (SEMrushBot) is inspecting the web app.

Answer (score -2):

update the timeout in web.config and in programming side add an attribute session.expires="milliseconds";